# Taking the return value of a process in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a C program, say `hello_world`. The main function returns an `int`. Can I access and use this returned value in a shell script?

This is the C code. I have written a very simplified version of my program. The actual code is 1.2K lines.

```
/*hello_world.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    if (argc == 2) {
        i = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("Hello World - %d\n", i);
        return 0;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

This is the bash script to run the executable generated after compiling the above code. I am using GCC 4.1.2 and compiling using `gcc -o hello_world hello_world.c`

```
#!/bin/bash
ret=hello_world 31 # this gives a `command not found` error
if [ ret -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "success"
fi
```

Is there any way I can access the returned value from the script?

Comment: I did search on Google as much as I could.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite a simple thing to do

```
hello_world 31
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "success"
fi
```

But if you want to capture the OUTPUT of the program

```
output=$(hello_world 31)
```

or

```
output=`hello_world 31`
```

Comment: What do you mean by `output`? The returned value?

Comment: anything that would normally be printed to stdout, so in this case, the string "Hello World - 31\n"